# sum a subquery and group by different column

Tags: sql, sql-server

as the title says, i need help on combining same result set, it's kinda hard to explain, so here's my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.liability_number AS CIF
    ,CASE 
        WHEN b.SECTOR = '1001'
            THEN 'I'
        WHEN b.SECTOR = '2001'
            THEN 'C'
        END AS [Customer Type]
    ,(
        SELECT ROUND(SUM(internal_amount) / 1000000, 0)
        FROM "limit"
        WHERE INSERT_DATE = '20200619'
            AND liability_number = a.liability_number
        ) AS [Previous Limit]
    ,(
        SELECT ROUND(SUM(internal_amount) / 1000000, 0)
        FROM "limit"
        WHERE INSERT_DATE = '20200626'
            AND liability_number = a.liability_number
        ) AS [Current Limit]
    ,ABS(ROUND((
                (
                    SELECT SUM(internal_amount)
                    FROM "limit"
                    WHERE INSERT_DATE = '20200619'
                        AND liability_number = a.liability_number
                    ) - (
                    SELECT SUM(internal_amount)
                    FROM "limit"
                    WHERE INSERT_DATE = '20200626'
                        AND liability_number = a.liability_number
                    )
                ) / 1000000, 0)) AS [Limit Difference]
    ,(
        SELECT ABS(ROUND(SUM(total_os) / 1000000, 0))
        FROM "limit"
        WHERE INSERT_DATE = '20200619'
            AND liability_number = a.liability_number
        ) + (
        SELECT ABS(ROUND(online_actual_bal / 1000000, 0))
        FROM account
        WHERE insert_date = '20200619'
            AND account_number = a.account
        ) AS [Previous Outstanding]
    ,(
        SELECT ABS(ROUND(SUM(total_os) / 1000000, 0))
        FROM "limit"
        WHERE INSERT_DATE = '20200626'
            AND liability_number = a.liability_number
        ) + (
        SELECT ABS(ROUND(online_actual_bal / 1000000, 0))
        FROM account
        WHERE insert_date = '20200626'
            AND account_number = a.account
        ) AS [Current Outstanding]
    ,(
        SELECT ABS(ROUND(SUM(total_os) / 1000000, 0))
        FROM "limit"
        WHERE INSERT_DATE = '20200626'
            AND liability_number = a.liability_number
        ) + (
        SELECT ABS(ROUND(online_actual_bal / 1000000, 0))
        FROM account
        WHERE insert_date = '20200626'
            AND account_number = a.account
        ) - (
        SELECT ABS(ROUND(SUM(total_os) / 1000000, 0))
        FROM "limit"
        WHERE INSERT_DATE = '20200619'
            AND liability_number = a.liability_number
        ) + (
        SELECT ABS(ROUND(online_actual_bal / 1000000, 0))
        FROM account
        WHERE insert_date = '20200619'
            AND account_number = a.account
        ) AS [Outstanding Difference]
    ,(
        SELECT COUNT(RECID)
        FROM "limit"
        WHERE INSERT_DATE = '20200619'
            AND liability_number = a.liability_number
        ) AS [Previous Loan Count]
    ,(
        SELECT COUNT(RECID)
        FROM "limit"
        WHERE INSERT_DATE = '20200626'
            AND liability_number = a.liability_number
        ) AS [Current Loan Count]
FROM "limit" a
JOIN customer b ON a.INSERT_DATE = b.INSERT_DATE
    AND a.liability_number = b.customer_no
WHERE a.INSERT_DATE = '20200626'
    AND a.l_tgl_loan >= '20200622'
    AND a.l_status_fas IN (
        '2'
        ,'3'
        ,'5'
        ,'17'
        )
ORDER BY a.LIABILITY_NUMBER;
```

and here's the result:

[image: current result]

what i want is:

[image: goal]

am trying to sum the subquery, and do group by, but whenever i tried it, it always gives me error :

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
> aggregate or a subquery.

So, how do i achive this?

Comment: Good use of whitespace is invaluable, that query much less readable before. Also, pictures of sample data and expected results don't help us help you, use tabular formatted `text` or DDL and DML statements. Good aliases choices are also important. There's not a single "a" in "limit", nor a single "b" is "customer", so why give them those aliases? [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 0):

Move all the subquery to the FROM statement, joining them with the main table, than in the main SELECT you call the fields already aggregated in the subquery